# Generating N random numbers from rand2()

Tags: c, random

The following `randn` function is used for generating random numbers, but I'd like to know how it works. What is happening in the loop there, and how it affects the resulting randomized value?

```
int rand2() {
    return rand() & 1;
}

int randn(int N) {
    int add = 0;
    int ref = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        add = add + rand2() * ref;
        ref = ref * 2;
    }
    return add % N;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("%d, ", randn(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It generates very bad random numbers one bit at a time.  Avoid it.

Comment: Sure, but just want to know how it is working? :)

Comment: Q: *"how it is working?"* A: not very well. You would actually get better results (and less code) with `int randn(int N) { return rand() % N; }` If you want to do the job right, check if your system provides the `arc4random_uniform` function.

Comment: the thing is I have to use `rand2()` function as the only input to `randn()`, its an interview question

Comment: For how to do the second part *correctly*, see http://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand2` generates either `0`, or `1`, so a random bit generator.

`randn` utilizes `rand2`, and does this in a binary-wise manner. So with input `N` which is the length of the binary value, it gets some random bit for every digit. But this value is converted to decimal in the end of every iteration.

With `N = 5`;

1. `rand2` returns `0`, `ref=1`, `add=0` (`0` in binary)
2. `rand2` returns `1`, `ref=2`, `add=2` (`10` in binary)
3. `rand2` returns `1`, `ref=4`, `add=6` (`110` in binary)
4. `rand2` returns `0`, `ref=8`, `add=6` (`0110` in binary)
5. `rand2` returns `1`, `ref=16`, `add=22` (`10110` in binary)

`ref` controls the binary to decimal conversion depending on the digit, and it has value of `ref = 2^i`. Its value in all iterations is representing the value of `1` bit in their respective spots in the binary, so a [*place value*](http://www.math.com/school/subject1/lessons/S1U1L1GL.html) in binary. When `rand2` result is `1`, `ref` value is added to the value of `add`, and when `rand2` result is `0`, `ref` is ignored, and value of `add` stays the same.

But in the end `randn` returns `add % N`, which is `22 % 5 = 2`, so in a way generating a random number of binary length `N` first, then uses the same length to get a random value between `0 to 4` again for the result, which is range `0 to (N-1)`. Somewhat weird way to generate random numbers, combines a randomized bit-wise value generation & its reduction to a smaller range with final modulo.